# How can you force functional programming immutability on minesweeper table?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, immutability

I am reading a lot about functional programming and immutability, and have a bit of a problem comprehending how you can make even a simple minesweeper game by not mutating the state? It is obvious that you have an initial state of the minesweeper table in an array ([0,0,0,0] - all tiles are hidden). But how can you reveal the tile if you do not record that change in the state ([0,0,1,0] - first tile in the second row is open)??

Here is a simple example of what I'm saying:

```
let minesweeperTable2x2 = [0,0,0,0];

let revealTile = ( tileNumber ) => {
  minesweeperTable2x2[tileNumber] = 1;
}

console.log(minesweeperTable2x2); // [0,0,0,0]
revealTile(2);
console.log(minesweeperTable2x2); // [0,0,1,0]
revealTile(0);
console.log(minesweeperTable2x2); // [1,0,1,0]
revealTile(1);
console.log(minesweeperTable2x2); // [1,1,1,0]
revealTile(3);
console.log(minesweeperTable2x2); // [1,1,1,1]
```

Is there anybody who is into functional programming and immutability and can explain to me this by converting the code I wrote to functional programming paradigm, respecting full immutability???

Answer (score 1):

You can re-create the table every time `revealTile` is called, and use that new table until it needs to be updated again:

```js
const initialTable = { ...[0,0,0,0] };

const revealTile = (lastTable, tileNumber) => {
  return { ...lastTable, [tileNumber]: 1 };
};
console.log(initialTable);
const nextTable = revealTile(initialTable, 2);
console.log(nextTable);
```

For an example of a slightly more complicated snippet that will run until all items of the array are revealed:

```js
const initialTable = { ...[0,0,0,0] };

const revealTile = (lastTable, tileNumber) => {
  return { ...lastTable, [tileNumber]: 1 };
};

const iter = (currentTable) => {
  const indexToReveal = prompt('Index to reveal? Currently ' + Object.values(currentTable));
  const num = parseInt(indexToReveal);
  if (indexToReveal === null || indexToReveal < 0 || indexToReveal > 3) {
    throw new Error();
  }
  const nextTable = revealTile(currentTable, indexToReveal);
  if (Object.values(nextTable).every(val => val === 1)) {
    console.log('Filled');
  } else {
    iter(nextTable);
  }
}
iter(initialTable);
```

This way, you're not *mutating* the state, but you're creating a *new* state every time a change needs to happen, and then passing along the new state everywhere it needs to be used.

Comment: It's important to note that in this code `initialTable` is not an array but an object with property names that are numeric (but nevertheless strings). In this case it still *works*, but may cause some surprises. For example, you won't be able to iterate over it with `forEach` or `for ... of`, and it doesn't have a `length` property. Also it may be harder for JavaScript engines to optimize, although in this particular application it probably doesn't matter since your data will always be pretty small.

Comment: Is this really the way the things are done in functional programming?? You made curried function with new variable for every state change?? But what will you do if you have thousands of state changes, will you make curried function with thousand levels?? Another, less important thing is that you used object, not an array that I used in my original code.

Comment: @Manzana You're saying "curred" but there's no currying here. Do you mean "recursive" (a function that calls itself)?

Comment: You're right Jordan, there is no currying, the function is recursive. The thing that's "bothering" me is that you avoided mutating one variable by mutating another. So, you don't mutate initialTable, but you mutate nextTable. It looks like it was easier in any way if you just worked on initialTable in the first place...

Comment: @Manzana There is no mutation in this code - functional programming avoids mutation. The `initialTable` object is not being mutated, nor are any of the intermediate `currentTable` objects. Yes, when you avoid mutation, code *does* sometimes get harder to write, but if you're trying to use functional programming (as your question implies), this sort of thing is the way to do it.

Comment: Yes, you could do some things more easily by throwing FP out the window and mutating, but the question was asking about FP

Comment: @Manzana Save all the characters in a state object, and update the state object when an attack is made: https://jsfiddle.net/adu46b1k/ Also note that, technically, `document.write` and `console.log` aren't entirely permitted either, in a fully functional script, because they cause side-effects.

Comment: @Manzana I completely agree that, in quite a few situations, the "code gymnastics" required to make a Javascript script conform to *all* the principles of functional programming is time-consuming and tedious without much gain. I definitely wouldn't recommend it, nor do I write code that way myself. (Though, if you're already working with a framework that works well with functional state, like React, it's somewhat easier.)

Comment: Writing functional code *when it doesn't make the logic convoluted* is perfectly fine, and probably desirable, bue writing functional code *absolutely everywhere* just for the sake of trying to follow a particular paradigm may well just make things more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

When working with immutability in mind the new state of the `minesweeper` is always returned by the transition function (`revealTile`), so that the given state is left intact.

```js
const revealTile = (n, minesweeper) => minesweeper.map(
  (value, i) => i === n ? 1 : value,
);

// ### ----

const minesweeper = [0, 0, 0, 0];

console.log(minesweeper); // [0,0,0,0]

console.log(
  revealTile(2, minesweeper),
); // [0,0,1,0]
```

Comment: Yes, but how you will change the next tile? Where you will remember the current state?? This is exactly what I am talking about. In your example, if you do another revealTile(1, minesweeper) all changes that happened before will be forgotten.

Comment: The currest state could be held by a state manager (redux for instance), or in a variable. The changes that happened before are not lost, since every snapshot is immutable, you will always have access to it. This is a basic time travelling...

Answer (score 0):

Most functional programming languages manage immutability for you. JavaScript isn't such a language, so you need to handle it yourself. You could use a library like [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer) or [Immutable](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/) for this, but it's not always necessary. Without a library, the usual approach is:

1. Create a copy of the object
2. Change the copy
3. Replace the original with the copy

In the case of updating a single element of an array, a straightforward implementation would look like this:

```js
function revealTile(table, tileNumber) {
  const nextTable = table.slice(); // create a copy
  nextTable[tileNumber] = 1; // update the copy
  return nextTable; // return the copy
}

let table = [0,0,0,0];

table = revealTile(table, 1);
console.log(table);

table = revealTile(table, 2);
console.log(table);

table = revealTile(table, 0);
console.log(table);

table = revealTile(table, 3);
console.log(table);
```

Comment: Thanks Jordan. So, in a matter of fact you DO mutate the state, just don't do it inside a function... The function stays pure. I just don't understand all those talks about immutable state?? Every app must record changes... It must mutate the state.

Comment: This reassigns the `table` variable though, and functional programming should not reassign variables - in functional Javascript, variables should always be declared with `const`, right?